# How to simulate Return and Escape for global command without using Control-V?

Tags: command-line, normal-mode, global-command

I've the following sample content which I want to edit:

```
<table>
<tr><td title="Title 1">col1</td><td>col2</td><td>col3</td></tr>
<tr><td title="Title 2">col1</td><td>col2</td><td>col3</td></tr>
<tr><td title="Title 3">col1</td><td>col2</td><td>col3</td></tr>
</table>
```

<sup>Note: It doesn't matter it's HTML, that kind of operation can apply to any format, so I'm not interested in HTML parsers.</sup>

Where I'd like to copy all values of `title` into separate column, so the expected result is:

```
<table>
<tr><td title="Title 1">col1</td><td>col2</td><td>col3</td><td>Title 1</td></tr>
<tr><td title="Title 2">col1</td><td>col2</td><td>col3</td><td>Title 2</td></tr>
<tr><td title="Title 3">col1</td><td>col2</td><td>col3</td><td>Title 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

My plan is to find all `td title` using global command (`g`) and execute normal commands:

1. Copy quoted text (`f"lyt"`).
2. Find `</td></tr>` (`/<.td><.tr>`, `<CR>`?).
3. Append `<div>` (`a<div>`, `<Esc>`?)
4. Paste yanked text (`p`).
5. Append `</div>` (`a</div>`, `<Esc>`?)

But I don't know how to simulate presses of <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Escape</kbd> after search or text appending.

I've tried this:

```
:g/td title/norm f"lyt"/<.td><.tr><CR>f>a<td><Esc>pa</td><Esc>
```

but it doesn't work, because `<CR>` and `<Esc>` aren't recognised as keystrokes.

Although it works when I insert these keystrokes manually while typing the command by using <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (`^M`) or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd> (`^[`).

Is there any alternative method where I can insert those keystrokes without using <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exec` the `norm` command. From [`:h :norm`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Anorm):

```
An alternative is to use :execute, which uses an
expression as argument.  This allows the use of
printable characters to represent special characters.

Example: 
        :exe "normal \<c-w>\<c-w>"
```

Note the usage of double quotes *and* the `\` before `<` for the special characters.

Your example would translate to something like:

```
:g/td title/ exec 'norm f"lyt"/<.td><.tr>' . "\<CR>f>a<td>\<Esc>pa</td>\<Esc>"
```

Here, I have used single quotes for the initial part of the command, both because it has `"` inside, and because single quotes give you a literal string without interpretation. Then, double-quoted strings where you need `<CR>`, `<Esc>` to be interpreted.

Comment: `\n` and `\e` can be used in place of `\<CR>` and `\<Esc>`, respectively, in an expression string - they're easier to type. Also, `\t` in place of `\<Tab>` and `\b` in place of `\<BS>`.

Comment: @djjcast, yes the full list being available at [`:h string`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#string).